# How to increase the gap between plotsymbol and plotsymboltext in line chart?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, linechart

I am drawing graph using core-plot framework and i am displaying text when user tap on polt-symbols. But my problem is, text is overlapping on the plot-symbol. How to over come this problem.Please help me.

[image]

and my code is like this

```
- (void) scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Green Plot"]) {
    selectedLineIndex1 = index;
    selectedLineIndex2 = -1;
    [graph reloadData];   
}
else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Blue Plot"]) {
    selectedLineIndex1 = -1;
    selectedLineIndex2 = index;
    [graph reloadData];
```

}
}

```
- (CPTLayer *) dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
// Setup a style for the annotation text
CPTMutableTextStyle *hitAnnotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
hitAnnotationTextStyle.color    = [CPTColor blackColor];
hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontSize = 18.0f;
hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Verdana-Bold";

// Now add the annotation text to the plot
CPTTextLayer *selectedText = [CPTTextLayer layer];
selectedText.textStyle = hitAnnotationTextStyle;
selectedText.position = CGPointMake(0.0,40.0f);

if (index == selectedLineIndex1 && [plot.identifier isEqual:@"Green Plot"]) {
    selectedText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",[[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]];
}
else if (index == selectedLineIndex2 && [plot.identifier isEqual:@"Blue Plot"]) {
    selectedText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",[[yPoints objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]];
}
return selectedText;}
```

is there any mistake tell me or is there any other way just suggest me please provide some samples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you drawing the text? An annotation? Data labels? Some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, just when i was creating line chart add a labelOffSet to line chart.

example code.

```
CPTScatterPlot *boundLinePlot2 = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle2 = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle2.miterLimit = 1.0f;
lineStyle2.lineWidth = 3.0f;
lineStyle2.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
boundLinePlot2.dataLineStyle = lineStyle2;
boundLinePlot2.identifier = @"Green Plot";
boundLinePlot2.dataSource = self;
boundLinePlot2.delegate = self;
```

i add this line to line chart so that my problem is solved.

```
boundLinePlot2.labelOffset = 10.0f;
boundLinePlot2.labelRotation = M_PI_4;
```